# Populating a dropdown with jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

I am populating a dropdown successfully with some code I found online.
My problem is this, I need the dropdown to also have another option of "Other".
How would I modify the script below to achieve this?

```
function populatemodelName() 
{
  $.getJSON('modules/car_sales/getcarmodels.php'
    , {makeName:$('#makeName').val()}, function(data) {

    var select = $('#modelName');
    var options = select.attr('options');
    $('option', select).remove();

    $.each(data, function(index, array) {
      options[options.length] = new Option(array['MODEL']); 
    });
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  populatemodelName();
  $('#makeName').change(function() {
    populatemodelName();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(select).append($('<option />').val('other').html('Other'));
```

Place it after your `each` loop (or before, if Other should be first in your list).